# Animated gif in IE stopping in case of multiple postbacks

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, http-post

I am using ajax to retrieve xml and xsl to create output HTML. when the processing is done, we are showing loading gif icons. For IE browser, the loading gif stops playing.. it freezes when there occurs an ajax postback. Could anyone suggest what could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution... which worked. There were multiple postbacks, so calling one ajax post function at callback of another with setting async = true in jquery ajax solved the issue. There was no need of reloading the image.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will be doing something like a jQuery's AJAX request. If so, in the `success` function, add this...

```
$.post({
    url: 'url',
    success: function(){
        $('img').attr('src', $('img').attr('src'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the approach.. since there are multiple postbacks.. this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Replace it with this way: `$('img').attr('src', $('img').attr('src') + (new Date()).getMilliseconds());`

Comment: Well.. I found a different solution.. changing post to get and then reloading the image seems to be working. But this isnt a proper solution.